# Cocos2D-X break the CCSprite to multiple triangles

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x-2.x

I would like to break the ccsprite in to multiple part. For that i am using Cocos2dx. What i am doing is that i am sub classing the CCsprite class and then doing the following code

```
    cocos2d::CCRenderTexture *rt = new cocos2d::CCRenderTexture();
    rt->initWithWidthAndHeight(sprite->getContentSize().width, sprite->getContentSize().height, cocos2d::kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGB565);
    rt->begin();
    CCSprite *s2 = CCSprite::createWithTexture(sprite->getTexture(), sprite->getTextureRect());
    s2->setPosition(ccp(sprite->getContentSize().width/2,sprite->getContentSize().height/2));


    s2->visit();
    rt->end();

    shatteredSpriteObj->setTexture(rt->getSprite()->getTexture());
    //shatteredSpriteObj->createWithTexture(rt->getSprite()->getTexture());
    cocos2d::CCRect spriteRect = sprite->getTextureRect();
    spriteRect.origin.x = 0;
    spriteRect.origin.y = 0;
    spriteRect.size.height = sprite->getContentSize().height;
    spriteRect.size.width = sprite->getContentSize().width;
    shatteredSpriteObj->setTextureRect(spriteRect);
    float   wid = sprite->getContentSize().width;
    float   hgt = sprite->getContentSize().height;
    float   pieceXsize = wid/(float)piecesX;
    float   pieceYsize = hgt/(float)piecesY;
    float   texWid = wid/shatteredSpriteObj->getTexture()->getPixelsWide();
    float   texHgt = hgt/shatteredSpriteObj->getTexture()->getPixelsHigh();
    //cocos2d::ccColor4B    color4 = {255,4,255, _realOpacity };

    cocos2d::ccColor4B  color4 = {_realColor.r, _realColor.g, _realColor.b, _realOpacity };
    TriangleColors  triColor4 = { color4, color4, color4 };

    //cocos2d::CCPoint *ptArray[piecesX+1][piecesY+1];
    std::vector<std::vector<cocos2d::CCPoint> > ptArray;
    for (int x=0; x<=piecesX; x++) {
        std::vector<cocos2d::CCPoint> row;
        for (int y=0; y<=piecesY; y++) {
            cocos2d::CCPoint pt = ccp((x*pieceXsize), (y*pieceYsize));
            if (x>0 && x<piecesX && y>0 && y<piecesY) {
                pt = ccpAdd(pt, ccp(roundf(randf(0.0, pieceXsize*0.45)), roundf(randf(0.0, pieceYsize*0.45))));
            }
            row.push_back(pt);
        }
        ptArray.push_back(row);

    }

    numVertices = 0;
    for (int x=0; x<piecesX; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<piecesY; y++) {
            if (numVertices>=SHATTER_VERTEX_MAX) {
                CCLOG("NeedABiggerArray!");
                return;
            }


            vdelta[numVertices] = ccp(randf(0.0, speedVar), randf(0.0, speedVar));
            adelta[numVertices] = randf(0.0, rotVar);
            colorArray[numVertices] = triColor4;
            centerPt[numVertices] = ccp((x*pieceXsize)+(pieceXsize*0.3), (y*pieceYsize)+(pieceYsize*0.3));


            vertices[numVertices] = tri(ptArray.at(x).at(y),
                                        ptArray.at(x+1).at(y),
                                        ptArray.at(x).at(y+1));

            texCoords[numVertices++] = tri(ccp((ptArray.at(x).at(y).x/wid)*texWid, (ptArray.at(x).at(y).y/hgt)*texHgt),
                                           ccp((ptArray.at(x+1).at(y).x/wid)*texWid, (ptArray.at(x+1).at(y).y/hgt)*texHgt),
                                           ccp((ptArray.at(x).at(y+1).x/wid)*texWid, (ptArray.at(x).at(y+1).y/hgt)*texHgt));

            vdelta[numVertices] = ccp(randf(0.0, speedVar), randf(0.0, speedVar));
            adelta[numVertices] = randf(0.0, rotVar);
            colorArray[numVertices] = triColor4;


            vertices[numVertices] = tri(ptArray.at(x+1).at(y),
                                        ptArray.at(x+1).at(y+1),
                                        ptArray.at(x).at(y+1));

            texCoords[numVertices++] = tri(ccp((ptArray.at(x+1).at(y).x/wid)*texWid, (ptArray.at(x+1).at(y).y/hgt)*texHgt),
                                           ccp((ptArray.at(x+1).at(y+1).x/wid)*texWid, (ptArray.at(x+1).at(y+1).y/hgt)*texHgt),
                                           ccp((ptArray.at(x).at(y+1).x/wid)*texWid, (ptArray.at(x).at(y+1).y/hgt)*texHgt));

        }
    }
```

and then overriding the draw method of CCSprite

```
    void CustomClass::draw(void){

       CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();

        cocos2d::ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(cocos2d::kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position  | cocos2d::kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shatteredSpriteObj->getTexture()->getName());
    glVertexAttribPointer(cocos2d::kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(cocos2d::kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, texCoords);
     glVertexAttribPointer(cocos2d::kCCVertexAttrib_Color,4,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0,GL_TRUE,colorArray);
    //glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices*3);

    }
```

But the problem is that the Sprite is becoming white colour and splitting. I know this is occurring because of giving this          glVertexAttribPointer(cocos2d::kCCVertexAttrib_Color,4,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0,GL_TRUE,colorArray);

I want like to know how to break the image itself.